# How to decrement a global variable in Javascript at the point it was incremented and vice-versa?

Tags: javascript

I have a working code that's basically increment or decrement a global variable `basenum` every 1 second depending on whether the `flag` value is true or false

```
var flag = true;
var basenum = 0;

var p = document.getElementById('result');
function foo1(){
  function bar(){
    result = basenum++;
    p.innerHTML = result;
  }  
  return bar;  
}
function foo2(){
  function bar(){
    result = basenum--;
     p.innerHTML = result;
  }  
  return bar;  
}

var baz1 = foo1();
var baz2 = foo2();

setInterval(function(){
  if(flag){
    baz1();
  }else{
    baz2();
  }  
}, 1000);
```

The problem is that I don't want to reset it back to zero eveytime the flag changes to true or false.
Currently, if flag is set to true, the innerHTML of p increments but when I change the flag to false, it reset to zero and then do the decrement.

All I want is that while its incrementing and I change the value of flag to false, the decrement starts at the last increment value and not zero.

Any idea how I can achieve that with my current code? TIA

heres [MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c6yqg3xo/3/)

Comment: How are you changing the value of the flag?

Comment: Um, your code already does that - I've added a button that changes the flag http://jsfiddle.net/c6yqg3xo/5/ (bear in mind that the flag switch doesn't affect the latest running intervalled function)

Comment: What's wrong with this: http://jsfiddle.net/c6yqg3xo/9/ ? (other than jquery)

Comment: How does flag change on the page?

Comment: Check your fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/c6yqg3xo/13/) I used another setInterval to reset the flag. your code is just fine.

Comment: Yes, your code is correct. But if you change the flag in JSFiddle, the execution is restarted. The changes in fiddle are not evaluated realtime.

Comment: yeah looks fine : http://jsfiddle.net/c6yqg3xo/14/

Comment: To change it when the fiddle is running, you could use Chrome Dev tool (F12), switch to Sources pane, click the first Pause button then write into consoleflag = false then resume execution

Comment: @all the flag will eventually changed depending on the value of another function which just return either true or false. I didnt actually tried putting a button to test the functionality but instead manually hard-coding the flag value and do a page refresh that's maybe causing the value to reset back to zero.

Comment: thank you all for shedding light. I resolved the problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

***check this if usefull***

```
$(".btncl").click(function (){
    flag = false;
}); 

var flag = true;
var basenum = 0;

var p = document.getElementById('result');
function foo1(){
  function bar(){
    result = basenum++;
    p.innerHTML = result;
  }  
  return bar;  
}
function foo2(){
  function bar(){
    result = basenum--;
     p.innerHTML = result;
  }  
  return bar;  
}

var baz1 = foo1();
var baz2 = foo2();

setInterval(function(){
  if(flag){
    baz1();
  }else{
    baz2();
  }  
}, 1000);
```